# Will REDIS give me fast In-Memory access to recent rows and fallback to a persistent store for long term entries?

Tags: database, architecture, redis

I'm **looking into REDIS**, and considering a scenario where I have a cluster with a master and one or multiple slaves.

Could I have a **partially In-Memory database** with **REDIS**? In-Memory for the most recent entries of a given table and stored in disk for the older entries?

Here's some requirements and what I'm expecting to deal with initialy

### Characteristics

- Relational data base is not required
- Very few tables **(only one is performance critical)**

  - I guess this one won't matter in a key value db?
- **Sub-second** access to **most recent** entries

  1. Most recent entries are about 100k rows (**In-Memory**)
  2. The **prevailing query** filters by a column that **matches multiple ids**, with **pagination** and always sorted **by most recent**.
- Performance is **not critical for older entries**
- Performance is **not critical for sorts other than the by most recent** entries

**Writes**

- **Very Few** but **Very Consistant** where each write inserts 20+ lines every 60 seconds
- Zero concurrency

**Reads**

- **Constant hammering** on a single table for the most recent rows
- Paging can be greatly reduced if necessary by doubling the page size
- 20+ reads per second **avg**
- 200+ reads per second **peak**

Will REDIS fit the bill? And if not, what solutions might fit this scenario? Is **partial In-Memory** even a thing?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it a single server? Is local cache a possibility here? Even faster than Redis, as there's no network communication, and no need for serialisation.

Comment: Multiple servers. However, if it makes sense to have the front-end in the same server without loosing the ability to scale, that would be possible. It would need to handle a lot of network requests. As for cache, I believe it might not fit here because of consistent writes that would invalidate it every 60 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Redis is a pure in-memory data store. You could use Redis for caching, and complement it with a persistent store (and handle the logic of this mechanism in the application), but Redis alone will not fit the bill.

I would recommend you have a look at Couchbase or Aerospike to get the best latencies from primary key accesses, if this aspect is important to you.

Otherwise, considering the throughput, a good number of persistent SQL and NoSQL stores can probably take care of your workload. For instance, MongoDB, MySQL or its derivatives, can be configured to achieve your goals with an adapted database model.

Comment: When you say, complement it with a persistent store (and handle the logic of this mechanism in the application), it means there is no support within REDIS to sync what's In-Memory with a persistent store? Is this correct? Would you recommend me to look to another solution, and which one (considering the problem I described, with in-memory for recent entries and persistence for long term entries). Thank you.

Comment: Exactly. Redis cannot synchronize with another persistent store. If you do not want to implement this in the application itself, you will be better served by another solution (mysql, mongodb, etc ...)

Comment: Redis **CAN** serve as a persistence storage. It's just have too few features comparing to RDBMS or NoSQL solutions: https://redis.io/topics/persistence

Comment: Redis cannot serve as a persistent storage if the data do not fit in memory (which is the use case here).